How to add internal DNS to existing Active Directory DNS Server
I am trying to utilize Active Directory DNS to service internal applications on a different domain. For example in AD we have a Forward Lookup Zone for blah.com. All of our internal addresses are stored here for servers and some sites for blah.com.
I have a need to add another domain for internal resources such as blank.com. I want to be able to set up the same configuration with the new Domain Name so when I go to blank.com I can point it to a local address so everyone on the domain can hit it.
I am not sure on what the best practice is here, but do I need to create a new Forward Lookup Zone with the blank.com domain name? Then I create the A/CNAME records in that Forward lookup zone?
Thanks!
I have not made any attempts to resolve this issue as I do not want to configure anything in Active Directory incorrectly and mess anything up.

Is blank.com another Active Directory domain? If so, I'd recommend creating a conditional forwarder from your user domain DCs to the other domain DCs. If not, and per the answer from ErkinD39, creating a new primary zone is fine. The main advice is to not duplicate hostnames and I endorse turning off dynamic updates for the standalone zone.

You can add a new forward lookup zone on the same server as the domain controller. For this case I reccommend to choose
Primary zone : Since this is a new zone and cannot be replicated from any DNS server as a secondary zone
Store the Zone: Active Directory . The reason for this recommendation is this zone will automatically be replicated to other domain controllers and you will have the option to secure each DNS record.
Replication Scope: If you plan other domain trees and domains in your forest and you will need this DNS zone records in other domains you may select Forest , if you plan to stay in the single domain you can either set domain or forest. The difference is the records are stored in different application partitions in Active Directory. Domain based replication scope stores DNS records in DomainDNSZones AD partition whereas Forest based replication scope stores DNS records in ForestDNSZones partition. The first partition automatically replicates to all DC s in the same domain whereas the latter one replicates to all domain controllers in the same forest.
Dynamic Update: I recommend 'Do Not Allow Dynamic Updates' if your clients are not planned to send dynamic DNS updates to this zone such as a specific DNS suffix.
How is the current Active Directory infrastructure affected?
You can define new DNS resource records, please be aware of the following:
Normally if you give totally another set of IP addresses and use different hostnames in your aplication no problem should occur.
But if you try to access the domain member and define a new host record pointing to the same IP address AND you have a reverse lookup zone updated by the new zone, problems may occur since DNS reverse lookup queries will load balance between two zone records. This might cause an issue in the existing AD domain.
I also suggest not to give the hostname portion of the new zone DNS resource records the same as the computer name of an existing domain member.
Please also be aware that Windows Integrated Authentication (Kerberos) will search for SPN registrations in AD, so if your application uses the new DNS domain names to access the applications such as app.blank.com, you can not enable Kerberos authentication until you register new SPNs in your domain controllers.
